# I noticed in Tkinter there were a few differnt ways to create a window, what is the most efficient or common/used most often?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Just confused, a little has to do with the syntax. I just want to know the best or most accepted term to set equal to Tk() to create a window. Is a certain term more acceptable, or standard? Using 5 differet terms depending on the tutorial, with basically the same exact code seems unlike Python, where easy to read, standard practiced words used and syntax seems weird, and had/has me a bit confused.

I had looked at the example in Tkinters modules file, and they use 'Frame' (many other guide do also), while after seeing frame,several more all have window, or root.

I understand that the window is the top level of windows (when set equal to Tk().

Was also very confused when windows were made, even though I was sure my code had errors, so I was experimenting, and merged random lines of two Gui's I made, and working. Created the code below, witch is bad I know. I guess windows are just always made? {EDIT} - I know the below code is wrong in many ways, I was testing things, and seeing if I could get the standard window that is created if you just run the code (even with errors I understand now), was seeing if I could get things to change, adding random things, and changing ect. I should have specified more, also posted one of my original working GUI but this is what I had open still.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.constants import *
window = tkinter.Tk()

frame = tkinter.Frame(tk, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=1)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=4)
label = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Welcome")
label.pack(fill=X, expand=8)
window = tkinter.Window(label, text="wtf")
window.title("My GUI")
frame = tkinter.Frame(tk, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=4)
tk.mainloop()
```

OK, above was me experimenting with 2 working GUI's I made and mixing random attributes, and options ect. I was confused how errors could exist and a window still be created, so was trying to essentially just see what worked at the same time make it so wrong it didn't make a window.

Just making sure I understand, x=tk.tkinter()  is just making the higest level window be stored in the variable x? If it is the second line, after importing tkinter. (anything can be x and the mainloop in this example window, root, tk, win, frame, ect)

So confusion started after looking at Tkinters actual files, and the modules code and (#) notes, explaining things. They used frame=Tk() and frame.mainloop().  After 3-4 tutorials with frame, all the sudden all I was finding was window=Tk(), or root, or tk. Same time classes were implemented in many tutorials using root and window.

I expected there to be that one main term/word to use. I guess I expected frame to be it, because it is inside the actual mods file and tkinter uses frame, shouldt everyone (at least at the the starter level guides, before classes and definitions or **init** is even implemented)? Just to be standardized and easy to understand?

I guess it can be many things? Does contect come into play? or are the terms I have mentioned usually just used? If so are any more generalized or accepted? I know it can be anything technically, and may be better for unique terms that describe that window, or if a personal project nobody will see, it doesn't matter as long as you see it. I just want to make sure my thingking is correct.

Frame being an attribute, that can have options , while the others just terms that do make sense (root makes the most as far as logically to me, or tk because it's short). Does anyone have experience what is used on some bigger projects, or if there is any tkinter projects with more than one creator what has been used most often? Seems many things used is just unlike python, usually things are simple, easy and go out of the way to make it all standardized so it looks as similar to code doing the same thing even if someone else uses it, type of ethics inside pythons communities.

Comment: The code you posted won't run for a number of reasons, and your questions don't make sense. There is no such thing as `Window` in tkinter, and there is no such thing as `tk.tkinter()` in your code.

Comment: OK, I have tried explaing the code you see so many times and ways, there is not enough room really to do that, and say anything else. I'll keep it at, that code was a one of the final _"tests"_ or experiments, I did using lines from two working GUI's. I kind of answered it my self, as asking the question and thinking. You just 100% cleared up 'Window' for me. Testing did the rest, was trying to make sure I understood the _Hierarchy_.  It was hard to ask, so much confusion, wasn't expecting a window to pop up every time I ran a code, if something was off, lead to me adding the 'text='.

Answer (score 0):

> How is line 3 usually used, refering [sic] to my example?

In the example, line 3 is this line:

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
```

You are free to use any variable name that you want. Most people tend to use `root` rather than `window` since you are creating the literal root window. It's possible to have more than one window, so `window` can be a bit vague.

> Root, Window or the frame (I think attribute) used worked well and is in the example, shouldn't that be the standard?

`frame` is the least correct, because frames and windows are two different things. As for standardizing, there are best practices but ultimately you are free to name things however you want. Again, most people use `root`, so it's the closest thing to a standard that we have for the root window.

Comment: (I type to much for this space lol) Thanks, I was just super confused that Tkinter inside the actual file, frame was used along with the first 3-5 tutorials. Then Window popped up on like 10 along with root. At the same time classes started to be used, and got me confused. Also a window being created with errors had me more confused, thought a window couldn't be created if errors existed. The above code was me trying to make a window not appear by doing random stuff essentially. I understand now (except class' def __init__ 100%).   Thanks, your guys answers made what I thought 100% concrete.

Comment: lol you understood exactly Bryan what I was trying to say thanks, it was hard to explain all that stuff. Now if only I can clode this or someone can lol